# Beautiful Soup: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am having a problem with Beautiful Soup and I cannot figure it out for the life of me. I am attempting to find an element and get the text inside it.

```
location = t.find('span', itemprop='name').get_text()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

However, if I run `location = t.find('span', itemprop='name')` I get the proper `Tag` object: `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> location=<span itemprop="name">Hobart, IN</span>`

What would cause this error?

Here is the full code:

```
with open('source.html') as f:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "html.parser")

# Extract script and style elements
for s in soup(["script", "style"]):
    s.extract()

tr = soup.find_all("tr")
for t in tr:
    location = t.find('span', itemprop='name').get_text() # ERROR
```

Source HTML is a table:

```
                <tr class="espresso-table-row live">
            <td class="event_title event-61492">Title of class</td>
                            <td class="venue_title event-61492"><span itemprop="name">Location</span></td>
                        <td class="start_date event-61492" data-value="1645452000">
                <ul class="ee-table-view-datetime-list">
                                                <li class="datetime-id-630">
                                February 21, 2022                           </li>
                                    </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="td-group reg-col" nowrap="nowrap"><a id="a_register_link-61492" class="a_register_link" href="https://website.com/">Register</a></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Strange indeed. Do you get the same error if you try: `for t in tr:
    location = t.find('span', itemprop='name') print(location.get_text())`?

Comment: Looks like not all table rows have a span inside them, could we see a snippet of the html to help?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to provide the HTML source. I've attached it above now.

Comment: @Jack Fleeting Yep it's really bizarre. Works fine up until you call the `get_text()` method and then it throws the error.

Comment: I tried it with the HTML source you provided and can't replicate the problem...

Comment: @ab217 - Your updated html works fine, but I am sure there must be another `<tr>` in your table that do not have a `<span>` you are looking for. Take a look at the example code in my answer. this will reproduce the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Question do not provide detailed information about the html, but it looks like there are `<tr>` selected that do not have any `<span>` with that attribute.

You should select your tags more specific for example with `css selectors`:

```
for span in soup.select('tr span[itemprop="name"]'):
    location = span.get_text()
```

#### Example

This html will lead with your code to an error cause your `find_all('tr')` is selecting both `<tr>` but in the second one you won't `find()` a `<span>` - result is None and None has no attribute `get_text()`. It will give you the location if you select it more specific.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<tr class="espresso-table-row live">
    <td class="event_title event-61492">Title of class</td>
    <td class="venue_title event-61492"><span itemprop="name">Location</span></td>
    <td class="start_date event-61492" data-value="1645452000">
        <ul class="ee-table-view-datetime-list">
            <li class="datetime-id-630">
                February 21, 2022
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td class="td-group reg-col" nowrap="nowrap"><a id="a_register_link-61492" class="a_register_link" href="https://website.com/">Register</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    any other content
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for span in soup.select('tr span[itemprop="name"]'):
    location = span.get_text()

print(location)
```

#### Output

```
Location
```